# Counting the number of lines (from result of grep) with a specific symbol in one column?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Say I have a file, file.txt:

```
F1 ID1 *
F1 ID2 *
F1 ID1 -
F1 ID3 *
F2 ID2 *
F1 ID3 *
F2 ID1 *
F1 ID1 -
F2 ID1 -
F2 ID3 *
```

The goal is to limit the file to just the rows with F1 in the first column, and find how many rows with '-' in the third column... and divide by the total number of rows with F1 in the first column.

```
F1 ID1 *
F1 ID2 *
F1 ID1 -
F1 ID3 *
F1 ID3 *
F1 ID1 -
```

In this case 2/6 = 0.333

What I've done so far:

I started with finding all rows where first column is F1 and store it in a variable,

```
result=$(grep F1 file.txt)
```

But it isn't doing what I want. Why is it that only the last line of the grep is stored in $result?

```
echo $result
F1 ID1 -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$ grep ^F1 test.txt | awk '{sum += 1; if($3=="-") dash += 1} END {print dash/sum}'
0.333333
```

Explanation:

- `^F1` means give me lines that begin with an F1
- output of that is sent to `awk`
- For each line awk gets, it increments `sum`; and increments `dash` if 3rd column is a `-`
- After reading all lines (`END`), prints the result of the math

Comment: Btw you could use `$3=="-"{dash++};` and then `END{print dash/NR}`

Comment: Ah, number of records could have been much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$ echo "scale=3; $(grep -c '^F1 [^ ]\+ -$' file.txt) / $(grep -c '^F1 ' file.txt)" | bc -l
.333
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat test.txt | awk '/^F1/{a++;if($3=="-")b++};END{print b/a}' # 0.33333
grep ^F1 test.txt | awk '$3=="-"{d+=1};END{print d/NR}' # 0.33333
```